# How is this a responsive <table>?

Tags: html, html-table, fluid-layout

I came across this template for a fluid newsletter-template.
I can understand the way how it works: It's a 100%-wide table with three '**td**'s. The first and third '**td**' wrap around the second '**td**' and their function can be seen while making the browser window smaller. What confuses me is the fixed width of the second '**td**'.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#ff0000">&nbsp;</td>
       <td width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#ff0000">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it has a defined static width of 600px, but when the window is smaller than 600px, it also gets smaller just like the other two '**td**'s beside it indead of giving you a horizontal scrollbar. Isn't a static width-definition "non-fluid"? How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default table has table-layout:auto; thats why it is adjusting on mobiles.
If it is set to table-layout:fixed; then it will break.
check this link 
[table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this is acting behind everything! I feel a bit ashamed that I overlooked that information.. Thank you for teaching me!